# Use of echo commands in batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have to convert a batch script to PowerShell. I came across these few lines of code and I have no idea what they do. Could someone explain it, especially the `echo` statements and `robocopy`?

```batch
set logdir=D:\Internal\Log
set runlog=%logdir%\run.log
set roboexe=robocopy /NJH /XX /NP

echo ^<!-- 1>>%runlog% 2>&1 
echo Move-Copy -  %account% %Time:/=% 1>>%runlog% 2>&1
echo Found files for %account% IN 1>>%runlog% 2>&1

%roboexe% "%fromdir%" "%historydir%" %wildcard% 1>>%runlog%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`echo`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772462.aspx) in shell just prints output to the screen. The command also works in PowerShell, but it's really an [alias](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_aliases) of [`Write-Output`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output), which sends output to the standard [success stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/)/pipeline (which if there's nowhere else for it to go, is the console/screen by default).

`Robocopy` is an advanced copying utility. It has a range of abilities beyond the standard copy function of Windows. It is documented [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx).

**To explain the tokens in this line:**

```
echo ^<!-- 1>>%runlog% 2>&1
```

`<`, `>`, and `>>` are [redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx). The `^` character escapes the `<` character so that it's being used literally rather than as a redirect. `!--` are also just being printed literally I believe.

`1>>` is using the append redirect to send the append the standard output to file specified in `%runlog%`.

`2>&1` redirects the error output stream to the standard output stream, so basically errors would also be written to the runlog.

Comment: Thanks Mark for quick response. What is meaning of numbers (1,2) in ECHO ^<!-- 1>>%runlog% 2>&1 
    ECHO Move-Copy -  %account% %Time:/=% 1>>%runlog% 2>&1 in these lines

Comment: Edited my answer with what I think is the explanation but i'm not a batch expert.